# Make request to api after the the first request is complete?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need two make 2 api calls

First one - I need to make api call to get price

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('mysite.com/getprice')
price = json.loads(req .read())
```

And second one - I need to make a buy request

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('mysite.com/buy?price=' + price )
```

I come from javascript, so I am wondering - do I have to worry about this calls made one after another and notat the same time like in js?

Answer (score 0):

Just like JS, Python also runs the program line by line. So, yeah, it's completely fine to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Python *requests* work synchronously, not like javascript where *ajax* requests are asynchronous.

So you do not worry and use *requests* one after another. They will execute in the same order they are called.